# I want to data type Conversion in a row in android

Tags: java, android

[image]

Hi.

I'm making an app that receives data from bluetooth by using stringbuilder

And makes it slice for using another activity.

The image shows what i want to make.

Q1. What should i use c->d, d->e ?

Q2. There will be a lot of data, I want to know the way to simplify this sequence

******************** edited  ********************

I have practiced by adding value to Arraylist.

But in String Array, there is no .get(), so i couldn't access to element's length.

```
public static ArrayList<String> randomValue = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int iDistance=0, xIAngle=0, yIAngle=0, zIAngle=0;
    public static String distance, xAngle, yAngle, zAngle;

       randomValue.add("12345090080070");
        randomValue.add("15640080085071");
       randomValue.add("16542070084074");
        randomValue.add("12645080087078");
        randomValue.add("21345084081060");
        randomValue.add("14785078075065");
        randomValue.add("13155079077077");
        randomValue.add("14623080078078");
        randomValue.add("14918086080078");
        randomValue.add("15684085082080");


        for (int i=0; i<randomValue.size(); i++){
            String a = randomValue.get(i); 
            String distance = a.substring(0,5); 
            String xAngle = a.substring(5,8); 
            String yAngle = a.substring(8,11); 
            String zAngle = a.substring(11,14); 

            //String to int
            iDistance = Integer.parseInt(distance);
            xIAngle = Integer.parseInt(xAngle);
            yIAngle = Integer.parseInt(yAngle);
            zIAngle = Integer.parseInt(zAngle);

        }
```

[image: edited]

Comment: What is happening at c->d? Nothing seems to happen there. The string array stays a string array. For `d->e` you can use a `for` loop with an `if` statement. What do you mean by "simplify this sequence"? Fewer lines of code? And why is "a lot of data" a reason for simplifying the sequence?

Comment: Thanks for adding comment.
1. I've just realized there is no difference between c and d.
2. I tried to make for loop. But all i can find was not length of element but length of array,  so i couldn't make a for roop.
3. the app will be got Fifty three thousand data. So i Want this sequence to be simple

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to remove the part about c->d, and show what you have tried?

Comment: sure. Wait for minutes

Comment: I suggest not to optimise prematurely. The way you are doing it is fine, there aren't any unnecessary steps except for c->d. If this is actually causing a performance problem (which you can check with a profiler), you can optimise it then.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am new in job, so i barely know about optimize. And i edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are just stuck on finding the equivalent of `get` for a string array. To access an element in an array, the syntax is `array[I]`, so if you were using a string array, this line:

```
String a = randomValue.get(i);
```

would have been:

```
String a = randomValue[i];
```

The code for your sequence of transformations can be shortened with Streams:

```
// this is the sequence of transformation starting with the sting builder "a"
List<String> randomValueWithLength14 = 
    Arrays.stream(a.toString().split(";")).filter(x -> x.length() == 14)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// this is the for loop shown in your code
for (int i=0; i<randomValueWithLength14.size(); i++){
    String s = randomValueWithLength14.get(i); 
    String distance = a.substring(0,5); 
    String xAngle = s.substring(5,8); 
    String yAngle = s.substring(8,11); 
    String zAngle = s.substring(11,14); 

    //String to int
    iDistance = Integer.parseInt(distance);
    xIAngle = Integer.parseInt(xAngle);
    yIAngle = Integer.parseInt(yAngle);
    zIAngle = Integer.parseInt(zAngle);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for Answering, but i have a question. I know to get lot of strings, stringbuilder is better than list. is it okay to use List<string> instead of stringbuilder?

Comment: @문경욱 If you could use a `List<String>` to start with, then please do. Then you don't need the sequence of transformations at all. You would be at step `c` already.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed codes just like you wrote. I think it's work although I can't check because of another problem ;( Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi @Sweeper I had tried and found that codes doesn't work.... ;( I'm so sorry for bothering you, but Could you help me more, please?

Comment: @문경욱 Is it related to my code or some other parts of your code? If it is some other parts of your code then you should post another question.

Comment: I have tried to make List<String> and add values into it, it worked. And I have checked that this app get data from bluetooth. So I think there is a problem on saving data. if you have a time, Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. there is an error, but not your code but somwhere else. I'm so sorry ;(